# Error parsing and output using Python webargs

Tags: python, rest, flask

Can [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) handle errors in JSON code in the payload and print a custom error message, instead of the default `400`?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from webargs import Arg
from webargs.flaskparser import FlaskParser

parser = FlaskParser()

app = Flask(__name__)

tracks_args = {
    'event': Arg(str, target='querystring'),
    'origin': Arg(str, validate=lambda w: w in ['suggest'], target='json', error='Invalid choice for     origin')
}

@app.route('/tracks/<string:event>', methods=['post'])
def post(event):
    args = parser.parse(tracks_args, request)
    print args
    print event

    return "OK"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8001)
```

A correct payload would be

```
{
  "suggest":"test"
}
```

with an incorrect one, that should print the error message, should be

```
{
   "suggestafasfaesfasef":"test"
}
```

Comment: https://webargs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#handling-errors

Comment: But it's not clear on the documentation that we have to write our own error handler to use the error message passed to Arg.